# Full screen image from gridview

Tags: android, image, fullscreen

How to delete an image from an activity? 
I have called images from specific folder and opening it in full screen image and i want to delete the image from the full screen activity.

Comment: please post your xml ....  `R.layout.activity_savednews`

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/thumbImage" android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

Comment: please edit your question ,it is not readable ....

Comment: Would you like to open it in alert dialog or acitivity?

Comment: Try my Project https://github.com/hiteshsahu/Awesome-Image-Gallery-Android

Comment: check new edited question

Answer (score 0):

Use a noactionbar theme in activity tag in AndroidManifest and then it will make it a fullscreen activity and you can use a match_parent in both width and height tag in imageview and show your image in that.

ex:

Answer (score 0):

```
delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     // Path to your image

      String path = "android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/myfolder/myimage.jpg";
      File file= new  File(path);
      if(file.exists()){

       file.delete();

      }
     finish();
    }
});
```

Comment: see updating post.

Comment: why you removed your previous question you have to update your question.